# how do I pass a different instance of the same model to a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that I want to open on the same page which works fine but I'm currently only passing it a new instance of the model it expects which therefore has no data. On the page there is a list of models,all of the same type, just with different values. What I want is when the "edit" button is click it requests in the controller to get the newest values, and return a model with that data and display it in the modal.

Currently I have the controller set up like this:

```
private FakeData.FakeBrandCategoryVM fakeBrandCategoryVM;
        // GET: BrandCategory
        public ActionResult BrandCategoryModal(int Id)
        {
            fakeBrandCategoryVM = new FakeBrandCategoryVM();

            BrandCategoryVM brandCategory = fakeBrandCategoryVM.GetFakeBrandCategoryVM().Where(x => x.SelectedCategory.CategoryId == Id).FirstOrDefault();

            return PartialView("_CreateOrUpdateBrandCategory", brandCategory);
        }
```

The "Edit" link is

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "BrandCategoryModal", new { Id = brandCategory.SelectedCategory.CategoryId, @data_toggle="modal", @data_target="BrandCategoryModal" })
```

This takes me to a different page with the model data and that is shown in the modal usng HTML helpers but the design is gone and it is just a plain form

Comment: `the design is gone` What do you mean by this?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap and when the design is there it has styling as the labels and edit fields are inside panels and are set sizes using the grid system in bootstrap. By the design being gone I mean that there doesn't seem to be any css styling. Come to think off it, that might be because it's changing to a different page instead of staying on the one it's already on it might not be inheriting from the _Layouy.cshtml file.